# Reload table data in Django without refreshing the page

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

The code to get the data in my view looks like this:

```
order = Order.objects.filter(owner=request.user).order_by('-id')[:10]
```

The code in my template looks like this and works great. Now, the thing is that i want this table to update its information every 10 seconds without refreshing the whole page. The url to the view is / and the name of the template is home.

```
           <table class="table table-striped table-condensed">
              <tr>
                <th>Reg.nr.</th>
                <th>M&auml;rke</th>
                <th>Modell</th>
              </tr>
              {% for i in order %}

                {% if i.order_booked %}
                <tr class="success">
                {% else %}
                <tr>                    
                {% endif %}

                 <td>{{ i.regnr|upper }}</td>
                 <td>{{ i.brand|capfirst }}</td>
                 <td>{{ i.brand_model|capfirst }}</td>
              </tr>
              {% endfor %}
            </table>
```

urls.py looks like this

```
urlpatterns = [ url(r'^$',views.home, name='home'), url(r'^login/', auth_views.login, {'template_name':'login.html'}, name='account_login'), url(r'^logout/', auth_views.logout, {'template_name':'logout.html'},name='account_logout'), url(r'^add_order/', views.add_order, name='add_order'), url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls), ]
```

Can anyone of you shed some light over this i would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: You need to use javascript. It's the only way to change the dom objects without refreshing the page.

Comment: Ok, im fine with using javascript. But i have no idea of how it should be done, I have tried dozens of scripts to try to get it to work. Do you have any experience in js with django and now how to get it done? How do i get new data from the view without refreshing the whole page?

Comment: It's really hard to get somebody from stackoverflow to write code for you. Simple googling something like "django with javascript" would give you tons of results. I just randomly pick one that looks promising http://www.tangowithdjango.com/book/chapters/ajax.html

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can use `setInterval`, `jQuery AJAX`, and a `view`:

**Your HTML**

```
   <table id="_appendHere" class="table table-striped table-condensed">
      <tr>
        <th>Reg.nr.</th>
        <th>M&auml;rke</th>
        <th>Modell</th>
      </tr>
      {% for i in order %}
        {% if i.order_booked %}
        <tr class="success">
        {% else %}
        <tr>                    
        {% endif %}

         <td>{{ i.regnr|upper }}</td>
         <td>{{ i.brand|capfirst }}</td>
         <td>{{ i.brand_model|capfirst }}</td>
      </tr>
      {% endfor %}
    </table>
```

**JS**

```
<script>
    var append_increment = 0;
    setInterval(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: {% url 'get_more_tables' %},  // URL to your view that serves new info
            data: {'append_increment': append_increment}
        })
        .done(function(response) {
            $('#_appendHere').append(response);
            append_increment += 10;
        });
    }, 10000)
</script>
```

**View**

```
def get_more_tables(request):
    increment = int(request.GET['append_increment'])
    increment_to = increment + 10
    order = Order.objects.filter(owner=request.user).order_by('-id')[increment:increment_to]
    return render(request, 'get_more_tables.html', {'order': order})
```

**get_more_tables.html**

```
  {% for i in order %}
  <tr>
    {% if i.order_booked %}
    <tr class="success">
    {% else %}
    <tr>                    
    {% endif %}

     <td>{{ i.regnr|upper }}</td>
     <td>{{ i.brand|capfirst }}</td>
     <td>{{ i.brand_model|capfirst }}</td>
  </tr>
  {% endfor %}
```

And then just make sure to add the new view into your `urls.py` **(make sure it has `name='get_more_tables'`, or whatever the name is in your JS `url:`)**

What this does is use `setInterval`, a JS function, to make a `GET` AJAX request every 10000ms (10 seconds) to a view in your server. The view then renders a separate HTML file using this new context, and sends it as a `response` back to your original HTML page. The new `response` is then `appended` via jQuery to your table. Every time this cycle happens, the slice is incremented, so you don't get the same results from `Order`.

Keep in mind that this will loop non-stop, so if you want it to end you will have to add code to the JS to stop `setInterval` if the last response came back empty.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will  try it out. It made me better understand what is needed. Thanks a lot.

Comment: No problem, if the solution works for you, be sure to click the green "check" mark to the left of my answer so that anyone who needs help will know the answer

Comment: Put your current urls.py in your original post and I will add it

Comment: Thanks for the code Hybrid, now it works like a charm. You really made my day, I have spent so many hours trying to work this out.