# Django: reload variable's value in the template

Tags: python, django

Imagine there is a Django HTML-template with a variable `foo`:

```
<div>
   {{ foo }}
</div>
```

Is it possible to reload `foo`'s value somehow without API call and without page reload?

Comment: If you find it let us know...! But there is some possible way... I think you are referring Http Api call then yeah the other way is web sockets...!

Comment: Thinks this approach with jquery and ajax may be helpfull : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34774138/reload-table-data-in-django-without-refreshing-the-page

Comment: `without API call and without page reload` that's a lot of restrictions you put on. Do you have a reason not doing any of those? Data won't reload from thin air.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching for an answer, I came to conclusion there is no way to update it without page reload or API-call. So, the solution is to change the approach.