# Automatically refreshing table in Django using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django, django-views

I am developing a code in Django and trying to refresh the table automatically. I have used jquery but it does not refresh the table.
Here is the my view: (views.py)

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import loader
from models import objectDB
def index(request):
    objects= objectDB.objects.all()
    template = loader.get_template('Myapp/index.html')
    context= { 'objects': objects}
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))

def refreshedindex(request):
    increment = int(request.GET['increment'])
    increment_to = increment + 10
    objects= objectDB.objects.all()
    template = loader.get_template('Myapp/refreshedindex.html')
    context= {'objects': objects}
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
```

Here is my table plus java script: (index.html)

```
<style>
#customers {
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

#customers td, #customers th {
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    padding: 8px;
}

#customers tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #f2f2f2;}

#customers tr:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

#customers th {
    padding-top: 12px;
    padding-bottom: 12px;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
}
</style>

{%  if objects %}
    <table style="width:100%" border="1" id = "customers">
      <tr>
        <th>obj Value</th>
        <th>item</th>
        <th>Type</th>
        <th>Tags</th>
        <th>Date First</th>
        <th>Date Last</th>
      </tr>
    {% for obj in objects %}
      <tr>
        <td>{{ obj.value }}</td>
        <td>{{ obj.item }}</td>
        <td>{{ obj.type }}</td>
        <td>{{ obj.tags }}</td>
        <td>{{ obj.date_first }}</td>
        <td>{{ obj.date_last }}</td>
      </tr>
    {% endfor%}
    </table>


{%  else %}
<h3>These is no obj to show</h3>
{%  endif %}

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var append_increment = 0;
    setInterval(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: {% url 'refreshedindex' %},  // URL to your view that serves new info
            data: {'append_increment': append_increment}
        })
        .done(function(response) {
            $('#customers').append(response);
            append_increment += 10;
        });
    }, 10000)
</script>
```

The following is the code the need to be used when the page will be updates (refreshedindex.html)

```
{% for obj in objects %}
  <tr>
    <td>{{ obj.value }}</td>
    <td>{{ obj.item }}</td>
    <td>{{ obj.type }}</td>
    <td>{{ obj.tags }}</td>
    <td>{{ obj.date_first }}</td>
    <td>{{ obj.date_last }}</td>
  </tr>
{% endfor%}
```

And this is the code of url.py.

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name= 'index'),
    url(r'^$', views.refreshedindex, name= 'refreshedindex'),

]
```

I have tried to fix the problem but I have no clue what is wrong here. Can you help me on solving this problem?

Comment: Where is the `#_appendHere` element that your Ajax done function is appending the data to?

Comment: Actually I do not know I am new to Django and just followed this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34774138/reload-table-data-in-django-without-refreshing-the-page

Comment: I changed it to the id of my table: #customers but still not working