# Refresh HTML table values in Django template with AJAX

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, django

Essentially, I am trying to do the same thing as the writer of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34774138/reload-table-data-in-django-without-refreshing-the-page) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47548863/django-dynamic-html-table-refresh-with-ajax?noredirect=1&lq=1) 
was trying to do.
Which is to dynamically update the values of an html template in a django template via an ajax call.

Both of them managed to fix their issue, however, I am unable to do so after 1.5 days.

`index.html`

```
{% extends 'app/base.html' %}
{%load staticfiles %}
{% block body_block %}
    <div class="container" >

        {% if elements %}
            <table id="_appendHere" class="table table-bordered">

                <tr>
                    <th>A</th>
                    <th>B</th>
                    <th>C</th>
                    <th>D</th>
                    <th>User</th>
                    <th>Date</th>
                </tr>

                {% for e in elements %}
                    <tr>
                        <td><a href="{{ e.A.url }}">{{e.A}}</a></td>
                        <td><a href="{{ e.B.url }}">{{e.B}}</a></td>
                        <td>{{ e.C }}</td>
                        <td>{{ e.D }}</td>
                        <td>{{ e.User  }}</td>
                        <td>{{ e.Date }}</td>

                    </tr>
                {% endfor %}  
            </table>

        {% else %}
            No data to display! <br/>

        {% endif %}
    </div>
{% endblock %}

<script>

var append_increment = 0;
setInterval(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "{% url 'get_more_tables' %}",  // URL to your view that serves new info
        data: {'append_increment': append_increment}
    })
    .done(function(response) {
        $('#_appendHere').append(response);
        append_increment += 10;
    });
}, 1000)

</script>
```

`views.py`

```
def index(request):

    elements = ElementFile.objects.all().order_by('-upload_date')
    context_dict = {'elements':elements}

    response = render(request,'app/index.html',context_dict)
    return response

def get_more_tables(request):
    increment = int(request.GET.get('append_increment'))
    increment_to = increment + 10
    elements = ElementFile.objects.all().order_by('-upload_date')[increment:increment_to]
    return render(request, 'app/get_more_tables.html', {'elements': elements})
```

`get_more_tables.html`

```
{% for e in elements %}
    <tr>
        <td><a href="{{ e.A.url }}">{{e.A}}</a></td>
        <td><a href="{{ e.B.url }}">{{e.B}}</a></td>
        <td>{{ e.C }}</td>
        <td>{{ e.D }}</td>
        <td>{{ e.User  }}</td>
        <td>{{ e.Date }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

`urls.py`

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name=''),
    path('get_more_tables/', views.get_more_tables, name='get_more_tables'),
        ]
```

in the javascript part, I tried:
`url: "{% url 'get_more_tables' %}"`, with and without quotes

If I try to access /get_more_tables/
I get the following error:

TypeError at /get_more_tables/

int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'

So for some reason, I get nothing, the append_increment is the empty dictionary. But why?
I tried altering the code like, but to no avail:

```
    try:
        increment = int(request.GET.get('append_increment'))
    except:
        increment = 0
```

Expectation: dynamically loading database
Outcome: error or non-dynamic loading (must refresh manually)

Million thanks to everyone who attempts to help with this.

Comment: In case it made any difference, three of the values are accessed via another object, e.g.
`<td>{{ e.D }}</td>`
should be
`<td>{{ e.someObject.D }}</td>`

Comment: request.GET is a query dict which works like this. 

>>> QueryDict('a=1&a=2&c=3')
<QueryDict: {'a': ['1', '2'], 'c': ['3']}>

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.__init__

Comment: as per the next error, (dynamic loading database)  can you check if the migration for the model you are trying to access is successfully applied

Comment: Thanks Krishna. Tried the migrations, but there were no changes. :(
If I print request.GET, I get {}, the empty dictionary. What am I doing wrong in your opinion?

Comment: 1. it's "method":"GET" not "type". 
2. you can check what request is going by checking network tab in chrome dev tools.

Comment: thanks for your response again.
1. sorry, not sure what you mean. just before you said request.GET is a query dict. now you refer to it as a method? and what does not "type" mean?
2. everything is empty in the Network tab

Comment: sorry for confusion. I was referring to javascript part of your code. where you wrote as { "type":"GET"}. 

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

as to chrome dev tools, you should open network tab first and then reload the page to capture the outgoing traffic.

Comment: okay, I see now, thanks. the linked two examples on stackoverflow had type , but I changed it to method - no change in the running of the app
In the network tab, if I reload index.html I just see the page and the loaded css and js files (all with status 200) 
if I reload get_more_tables.html, I just the the page itself with 200

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188520/discussion-between-krishna-chaitanya-kornepati-and-mrg).

Comment: Thanks, Krishna, managed to get it working. To the others wondering, url: "{% url 'get_more_tables' %}" this must be just url: "get_more_tables/" in the js file